# What does the Dream Room do?

Tags: tiny-monsters

I have a quest to build the Dream Room.  So far I haven't seen any explanation of what the Dream does.  The in game text says:

> After observing that monsters evolved during a prolonged deep sleep, Phineas Alexander suggested the explorers build a specialized hibernation center known as the Dream Room. Carved into an enormous tree, the building ensures the creatures have the most relaxing and peaceful sleeping situation possible while simultaneously protecting them during hibernation.

What do I use the Dream Room for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it to turn baby monsters into teens and teens into adults.

Comment: Hey Loll loo welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

If you need more information, check out 
http://tinymonsters.wikia.com/wiki/

And add what you've found so far too!
Since the game is so new, not everything is out there yet

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! Whilst this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to quote the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.